# Salesforce Products and Tiered Product Pricing Structure

Tags: product, pricebook

I am converting our organization to use the Salesforce Products and Price Books features. I've been searching for articles and guidance on best practices and have a basic knowledge of how all of that works. However, I'm not sure how to best implement our product structure in Salesforce and would love some help/guidance from those that have a lot more experience doing this.

Our product has tiered pricing based on the quantity purchased. So it looks something like the following:

- If you buy 5 of Product A, then the pricing is $190 each
- If you buy 10 of Product A, then the pricing is $150 each
- If you buy 15 of Product A, then the pricing is $140 each
- If you buy 20 of Product A, then the pricing is #135 each
- Etc.

And the tiers go all the way up to 200, where the per product price is discounted down to $105 each, with each tier being discounted from the previous tier. The tiers are structured around increments of five each.

Given this kind of tiered product and pricing approach, what is the best way to handle this in Salesforce using the product object and price books?

Thanks for any help or guidance you can provide. Also, I'm not sure if this is allowed or not, but I'd love to hire someone to help guide/consult with me in making these changes and some other things we need to do to improve how we're using Salesforce. DM me if you're interested. (if this isn't allowed here, I'll edit this part out of my post).

Thank you!

Comment: [CPQ has this out of the box](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/discounting-tools-in-salesforce-cpq/set-up-volume-based-discount-schedules). Non-CPQ, e.g. Sales Cloud:  [vote for this idea](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000BrG1AAK)

Answer (score 0):

Realistically, what you're looking for is [Salesforce CPQ](https://www.salesforce.com/products/cpq/resources/what-is-salesforce-cpq/). However, if you're not willing to upgrade (I don't know what the cost is, so you'd have to ask), then you'd have to build this.

At a basic level, you could build identical products, but priced differently (e.g. you'd have a product for each of up to 5, 5-10, etc).

This is quite a bit of manual maintainence, and you might also want validation rules to make sure the product matches the volume discount range (e.g. so users don't give someone the 200+ discount for a quantity of 5).

You could also choose to use some automation to calculate the correct price for the product. This would be pretty easy to set up with a flow or some code.

Because Salesforce is entirely flexible, you have a lot of options. If you want to build something custom, but don't know where to start, a consultant is definitely not a bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this helps people with similar questions: in Salesforce B2B Commerce and B2B2C Commerce, there is an option "Set up price tiering" which does exactly what is needed: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.comm_pas.htm&type=5